Existence of measurable section
Let $P \subset S^{d-1} \times \mathbb{R}^d$ be a compact set such that $proj_{S^{d-1}}(P) = S^{d-1}$, I want to show that there exists a Borel measurable map $ f \, : \, S^{d-1} \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $(\omega,f(\omega)) \in P \forall \omega \in \mathbb{R}^d$.
I think the Jankov, von Neumann Uniformization theorem would show it, but I wanted to find some more elementary way.
I think something like $f(\omega) := \max\{ x \; : \; (\omega,x) \in E\}$, where the maximum is respect to the lexicographic order, would work, but I don't know how to show it.

For your $f$ and any $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ the set $\{y\in S^{d-1}\mid f(y)>_{lex} x\}$ is a countable union of (projections of compact sets and thus again) compact sets and thus Borel, this is because $S^{d-1}\times\{z>_{lex}x\}\cap P$ is a union of compact sets.
Edit: We can assume that $P\subseteq S^{d-1}\times [-C,C]^d$ for some $C>0$. For any compact Polish space $H$ consider the hyperspace of its compact subset $K(H)=\{L\subseteq H\mid L \text{ is compact}\}$ with the topology generated by the sets $K_U=\{L\mid L\subseteq U\}$ and $K^U=\{L\mid L\cap U\neq \emptyset\}$, where $U\subseteq H$ is open. This topology again is a compact Polish topology.
Now, if $L,M$ are compact Polish spaces and $P\subseteq L\times M$ is compact, then the map $L\rightarrow K(M)$, $x\mapsto P_x=\{y\mid (x,y)\in P\}$ is Borel. To see this, let $U\subseteq M$ be open and let $K_n\subseteq U$ be a sequence of compact sets whoose union is $U$.  Then $P_x\cap U\neq \emptyset$ iff $x$ is in one of the projections of $(L\times K_n)\cap P$ onto $L$. As the latter sets are compact, the preimage of $M^U$ is Borel. As these sets generate the Borel sets, we are done.
It remains to show that the map $K([-C,C]^d)\setminus \{\emptyset\}\rightarrow [-C,C]^d$, $L\mapsto$ the lexicographically maximal element of $L$, is Borel.
Let $p_i$ denote the projektion onto the $i$th coordinate.
The map $d_1:K([-C,C]^d)\setminus \{\emptyset\}\rightarrow [-C,C]^d$, $L\mapsto \max p_1(L)$ is Borel.
In general the map $K(L)\times K(M)\rightarrow K(L\times M)$, $(H,I)\mapsto H\times I$ is continuous, thus Borel.
Also the map $K(L)\times K(L)\rightarrow K(L)$, $(H,I)\mapsto H\cap I$ is Borel. To see this, let $U\subseteq L$ be open and let $K_n\subseteq U$ be a sequence of compact sets whoose union is $U$. Then $H\cap I\cap U= \emptyset$ iff $H\cap I\cap K_n= \emptyset$, for all $K_n$. But $H\cap I\cap K_n= \emptyset$ iff  there exists open sets $V,W\subseteq L$ such that $V\cap W\cap K_n=\emptyset$ and $I\in L_V$ and $H\in L_W$. This is an open set of $ K(L)\times K(L)$.
Recursively define $d_{i+1}(L)=\max p_{i+1}(L\cap (\{d_1(L)\}\times...\times \{d_i(L)\}\times [-C,C]^{d-i})) $.
As a composition of Borel maps this map is Borel, but $(d_1(L),...,d_d(L))$ is the lexicographically maximal element of $L$.

I need that for every Borel measurable $B \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ the set ${ y \in S^{d-1} , : , f(y) \in B}$ is Borel measurable, but you're showing it just for $B = { z >{lex} x}$, maybe it's because the sigma algebra generated by the sets ${z >{lex} x}$ is the full Borel sigma algebra, but I don't see why.

I think these sets generate the entire Borel sets. It is enough to show that they contain the open sets. This goes somehow like this: By countable intersection we get ${z\leq_{lex}x}$ and thus we have sets of the form  ${z<{lex}x}\cap {z>{lex}y}$ in there, and any open set of the form $(a,b)\times \mathbb{R}^d$ is a countable union of such sets. Any open set is countable union of finite intersections of such sets.

I don't see how any open set is countable union of finite intersections of such sets.

I see you point. I now don't think these sets generate the Borel sigma algebra (unless $d=1$). But maybe something along the lines works, if one directly shows that $f^{-1}$ of any open set is Borel maybe.

Let d=2. Then the sigma algebra generated by these sets is a subset of the sigma algebra $S$ given by $A\in S$ iff $A$ is Borel and the set ${x\mid A_x\text{ is meager}}\cup {x\mid A_x\text{ is comeager}}$  is comeager. This is a proper subalgebra of the Borel sets, thus they do not generate all Borel sets.
